# Python how to initiate a new instance with another instance's attribute without referencing its original instance?

Tags: python

I have one class defined as below:

```py
class Lock():
    def __init__(self, shape='', path=[]):
        self.shape = list(shape)
        self._path = path
```

I am trying to define a new function to get the neighbors of this self instance:

```py
    def neighbors(self):
        nodes = []

        for i,wheel in enumerate(self.shape):
            for j in (1, -1):
                lock = Lock(self.shape, self.path)
                shape = lock.shape
                num = int(wheel) + j
                if num == -1:
                    num = 9
                elif num == 10:
                    num = 0
                shape[i] = str(num)

                lock.add_path(shape)
                nodes.append(lock)

        return nodes
    def add_path(self, x):
        self._path.append(x)
```

The problem happened to be wrong on this line:

```py
lock = Lock(self.shape, self.path)
```

, where I noticed, if I changed the new instance lock.shape or lock.path, the self instance attribute is changed together. So after the for loop, the self._path attribute is modified many times. I understand it's because lock attribute is referring back to self attribute so it's in the end change self's attribute.

Instead of using copy module, is there a way I can separate the reference to old instance but using its value instead?

Comment: The way you're currently doing it, `self.shape` shouldn't be displaying this behavior (because `list()` returns a softcopy) but `_path` should be. Try passing a copy-slice into the constructor: `lock = Lock(self.shape[:], self.path[:])`. This should create a softcopy of the list without having to invoke the `copy` module.

Comment: oh yes, self.shape isn't showing that behavior. so I tried your suggestion also changed self._path = list(path) which works too. If you post your answer, I would accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists come with other ways to create a softcopy without invoking the `copy` module. Here are several:

```
lst = [1, 2, 3]
lst[:]       # copy-slice
list(lst)    # creates a new list with the same set of elements
lst.copy()   # the list class has this method
```

Simply use any of these before calling the constructor, and it should behave like you want:

```
lock = Lock(self.shape[:], self._path[:])
```

(note that currently you don't *need* to do this with `.shape`, since the constructor already copies it with `list()`, but it doesn't hurt either)